# systemctl service systemd-notify not working with non-root user

Tags: bash, systemd, rhel7, systemctl

I have a simple example of a service unit and bash script on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 using `Type=notify` that I am trying to get working.

When the service unit is configured to start the script as root, things work as expected.  When adding `User=testuser` it fails.  While the script initially starts (as seen on process list) the `systemctl` service never receives the notify message indicating ready so it hangs and eventually times out.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Test
[Service]
Type=notify
User=testuser
ExecStart=/home/iatf/test.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Test.sh (owned by testuser with execute permission)

```
#!/bin/bash

systemd-notify --status="Starting..."
sleep 5
systemd-notify --ready --status="Started"

while [ 1 ] ; do
  systemd-notify --status="Processing..."
  sleep 3
  systemd-notify --status="Waiting..."
  sleep 3
done
```

When run as root systemctl status test displays the correct status and status messages as sent from my test.sh bash script.  When `User=testuser` the service hangs and then timesout and `journalctl -xe` reports:

```
Jul 15 13:37:25 tstcs03.ingdev systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 7193.
Jul 15 13:37:28 tstcs03.ingdev systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 7290.
Jul 15 13:37:31 tstcs03.ingdev systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 7388.
Jul 15 13:37:34 tstcs03.ingdev systemd[1]: Cannot find unit for notify message of PID 7480.
```

I am not sure what those PIDs are as they do not appear on ps -ef list

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be known limitation in the `notify` service type

From a [pull request](https://github.com/binarin/systemd/commit/d2d10f5c645b4f8fb01cbe3100b7938293e703ac) to the `systemd` man pages

```
    Due to current limitations of the Linux kernel and the systemd, this
    command requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN privileges to work
    reliably. I.e. it's useful only in shell scripts running as a root
    user.
```

I've attempted some hacky workarounds with `sudo` and friends but they won't work as `systemd` - generally failing with

```
No status data could be sent: $NOTIFY_SOCKET was not set
```

This refers to the socket that `systemd-notify` is trying to send data to - its defined in the service environment but I could not get it reliably exposed to a sudo environment

You could also try using a Python workaround described [here](http://dietrichschroff.blogspot.com/2018/08/systemd-systemd-notify-not-working-for.html)

```
python -c "import systemd.daemon, time; systemd.daemon.notify('READY=1'); time.sleep(5)"
```

Its basically just a sleep which is not reliable and the whole point of using `notify` is reliable services.

In my case - I just refactored to use `root` as the user - with the actual service as a child under the main service with the desired user

Comment: Cannot find this in the man page anymore. Has this been resolved?

Comment: @adrelanos my research last night indicates that this was fixed in systemd 246 (which hasn't landed in ubuntu 20.04 though). In particular, [this PR](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/15547), which fixes the issue, first landed in 246-rc1.

Comment: @djsavvy Very likely chance that systemd 246 won't ever land in 20.04 - given systemd is the init system its basically locked in for the lifetime of the OS. If this is something you want I'd be looking at newer operating systems

Comment: I do not understand why there is `time.sleep(5)` in python workaround. I removed it and I noticed that sometimes notification does not work because timeout occurs. I am confusing if removing `sleep` is responsible for it. Is `sleep` really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

sudo -u USERACCOUNT_LOGGED notify-send "hello"

Answer (score -1):

You can add `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to the unit file:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_ADMIN
User=someUser
```

Also, to avoid race-condition issues, the service should send `BARRIER=1` after `READY=1`.

See https://man.archlinux.org/man/sd_notify_barrier.3.en

---

Note: If SELinux (Mostly for RedHat OS) is enabled:

```
root# getenforce
Enforcing
```

Add `systemd_notify_t` to the permissive types:

```
semanage permissive -a systemd_notify_t
```

You can check with:

```
semanage permissive -l
```

Comment: This isn't relevant to the (now very old) distro and systemd version this question is about, which had a separate (now resolved) bug that prevented correct operation even without SELinux in play. Consider asking a new, SELinux-specific question and posting this as an answer to it.